# simple sql to select topper

Tags: sql, select

I have table `stud_id` (`key,name,standard,marks`). I want to select topper from each `standard`. Will the following query work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT( standard ), 
               stud_id, 
               name, 
               marks 
FROM   table 
WHERE  marks = Max(marks) 
GROUP  BY standard
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: You have your database and a SQL client there.  Does that query return what you expect?

Comment: Actually that was an interview question. I didn't got a chance to try this kind of thing.

Comment: one who is the highest marks in a standard

Comment: @DanBracuk Considering they are using `max`, I am guessing top or highest marks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the top `marks` for each `standard`, then you can use:

```
select t1.standard,
  t1.stud_id,
  t1.name,
  t1.marks
from table t1
inner join
(
  select standard,
    max(marks) TopMarks
  from table
  group by standard
) t2
  on t1.standard = t2.standard
  and t1.marks = t2.topmarks
```